# Explicit extinction probability of busy period

Tags: queueing-theory

Let $Q$ be a M/G/1-queue. We denote by $B$ the busy period of the queue, that is defined as follows:
$$B:=\inf \{ t>0: Q(t+T_1)=0 \},$$
where $T_1$ is the arriving time of the first costumer.

> Theorem: $$\Pr(B<\infty)
> \begin{cases}
> =1 & \text{ if } \rho \leq 1, \\
> <1 & \text{ if } \rho >1.
> \end{cases}$$

How can I explicitly compute $\Pr(B<\infty)$ in the case when $\rho >1$?

$Z_n$ denotes the number of customers in the $n$th generation, where $Z_0=1$. Then we know that $$\Pr(B<\infty)=\Pr(Z_n=0 \text{ for some } n).$$
Now I have seen, that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}G_n(0)=\Pr(Z_n=0 \text{ for some } n),$$
where $G_n(s):=\mathbb{E}[s^{Z_n}]$ is the generating function of $Z_n$.

But is it possible to compute $G_n(s)$?

Comment: You are starting with an empty system and are particularly interested in the probability of the first busy period having a finite length, i.e. $\mathrm{Pr}(B<\infty)$?

Comment: Yes! it is a kind of a branching process. In the beginning there is always 1 customer. Then in the time he is getting served, other customers are joining the queue. Now we are interested when there are no customers in the queue, i.e. $Z_n=0$. So that the server is free and not busy.

Comment: I guess you might want to look up random walks with an absorbing barrier and try to apply that here. One starts in state $1$ and tries to find the probability of ever arriving in state $0$ (which is the absorbing state) when the drift of the random walk is towards $+\infty$. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Once the $n$th generation of customers has been suitably defined (which is not a trivial task), the branching process representation mentioned in the question shows that the extinction probability $P(B\lt\infty)$ solves $$\theta=E(\mathrm e^{-\lambda(1-\theta)X}),\tag{$\ast$}$$ where $\lambda$ denotes the rate of arrivals and $X$ the (random) service time of any given customer. When $\rho=\lambda E(X)$ is such that $\rho\gt1$, then the root $\theta$ of $(\ast)$ which is in $(0,1)$ is the  extinction probability.

There is usually no simple formula for the generating functions $G_n$.